# why memory usage is always increasing when use python2.7 Queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I wrote a multiprocess program, one process with two threads dispatching tasks and collecting results, multi-process get task from the task_queue and put the result in result_queue. It looks like the following:
task_master.py

```
import threading
import random, time, Queue
from meliae import scanner
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def dispatch_task(task):
    print threading.currentThread()
    for i in xrange(100000):
        task.put(i)
        print "task %d has been put into queue" % i 

def get_result(result):
    print threading.currentThread()
    i = 0 
    while True:
        r = result.get()
        print r
        i = i + 1 
        if (i % 100 == 0): 
            scanner.dump_all_objects('dump%s.txt' % time.time())




if __name__ == "__main__":
    task_queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=100)
    result_queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=50)

    QueueManager.register('get_task_queue', callable=lambda: task_queue)
    QueueManager.register('get_result_queue', callable=lambda: result_queue)

    manager = QueueManager(address=('', 5000), authkey=b'abc')
    manager.start()

    task = manager.get_task_queue()
    result = manager.get_result_queue()

    task_thread = threading.Thread(target=dispatch_task, args=(task,))
    result_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_result, args=(result,))

    task_thread.start()
    result_thread.start()

    print "task thread has started"
    print "result thread has started"

    while True:
        if not task_thread.isAlive() and not result_thread.isAlive():
            break


    manager.shutdown()
    print('master exit.')
```

task_worker.py

```
import os
import uuid
import numpy as np
import time, sys, Queue
import random
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import Process

Max_Process = 10

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

def process_task(task, result):
    r = list()

    while True:
        t = task.get()

        for i in xrange(10):
            a = list()
            a.append(uuid.uuid1())
            for j in xrange(10):
                a.append(random.random())

            r.append(a)

        print "pid: %d, result %d is waiting to put into queue" % (os.getpid(), t)
        result.put(r)
        print "pid: %d, result %d has been put into queue" % (os.getpid(), t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QueueManager.register('get_task_queue')
    QueueManager.register('get_result_queue')


    server_addr = '127.0.0.1'
    print('Connect to server %s...' % server_addr)

    m = QueueManager(address=(server_addr, 5000), authkey=b'abc')

    m.connect()

    task = m.get_task_queue()
    result = m.get_result_queue()

    plist = list()
    for i in xrange(Max_Process):
        p = Process(target=process_task, args=(task, result,))
        plist.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in plist:
        p.join()

    print('worker exit.')
```

The memory usage of task_master is always increasing while i have set the maxsize of result_queue.

```
Pid : 7092, rss: 18816 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 83808 
Pid : 7092, rss: 18824 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 84292 
Pid : 7092, rss: 19620 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 93280 
Pid : 7092, rss: 19868 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 95424 
Pid : 7092, rss: 19964 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 95648  
Pid : 7092, rss: 20752 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 98948 
Pid : 7092, rss: 20672 ;Pid : 7093, rss: 102624
```

And I use meliae.loader to analyasis the memory useage of task_master, it looks like the following:

```
from meliae import loader
om = loader.load('dump1515814558.29.txt')
om.summarize()


p = om.get_all('list')
print len(p)
print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
print p[0]
print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
print p[0].c

print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
print p[0].p
```

The result is :

```
loaded line 43206, 43207 objs,   4.3 /   4.3 MiB read in 0.5s        
checked    43206 /    43207 collapsed     1813    
set parents    41393 /    41394            
collapsed in 0.2s
1832
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
list(4432453288 14520B 1600refs 1par)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[list(4433209392 216B 11refs 1par), list(4433209320 216B 11refs 1par), list(4433209248 216B 11refs 1par), list(4433209176 216B 11refs 1par), ...]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[frame(4426104912 456B 7refs 1par 'get_result"')]
```

I am very confused, why the memory usage is increasing while i have set maxsize of the queue, any answers will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is `r` ever cleared?

Comment: no, i think after execute r = result.get(), the previous r will be collected by gc, so it does not have to del r specially. right?

Comment: Ahh.. maybe in the get_result. That seems like an odd way to handle it.

Comment: The memory usage increases when there is a max_size compared to when it is not set? (And how much more memory is used?)

Comment: If not set max_size, the memory usage increases much more faster, and i think it depends on the num of task_worker process. If set max_size, the memory usage increases slowly, but it always increases, from 30M to 100M or even more. It looks like that the list was not removed from the result queue when get method was called.